Docker macvlan mtu behaviour on container startup vs. interface bounce
Why does a container inherent the correct mtu from the docker host->network on startup, but not on an interface bounce?
Docker host interface eno2 has 9202 configured as it's mtu:
$ ip link show eno2
4: eno2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9202 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:e0:ed:fa:1d:a3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp244s0f0

A container connected to a macvlan network using eno2 as a parent will inherit this mtu on startup:
$ docker network create -d macvlan -o parent=eno2 mtu_test_net
8a39afa66a33378eaf9f1bcf9ebb83b7c5c6840ad97dfc4ee4ac8f2a1083a954
$ docker run --network mtu_test_net -it alpine /bin/sh
/ # ip a show dev eth0
174: eth0@if4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP,M-DOWN> mtu 9202 qdisc noqueue state UP 
    link/ether 02:42:ac:14:00:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.20.0.2/16 brd 172.20.255.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
/ # 

When the parent interface is shutdown, mtu is reset to default:
$ sudo ip link set dev eno2 down

/ # ip a show dev eth0
174: eth0@if4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP,M-DOWN> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP 
    link/ether 02:42:ac:14:00:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.20.0.2/16 brd 172.20.255.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
/ # 

When the parent interface is restored, mtu is not inherited from the host:
$ sudo ip link set dev eno2 up
$ ip link show dev eno2
4: eno2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9202 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:e0:ed:fa:1d:a3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp244s0f0

/ # ip a show dev eth0
174: eth0@if4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP,M-DOWN> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP 
    link/ether 02:42:ac:14:00:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.20.0.2/16 brd 172.20.255.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
/ # 

I'm looking to better understand the problem, I'm not asking about ways to fix it; I understand that I can ip link set dev eth0 mtu 9202 the container.  I also understand that Docker macvlan networks don't support setting the mtu.
